# How to Run an executable file on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, mono, raspberry-pi, pyinstaller

I want to convert .py file into an executable file and run on raspberry pi. I installed pyinstaller

```
sudo apt-get install pyinstaller
sudo pyinstaller test.py
```

This command create a test.spec file and dist folder.

```
cd dist/test
```

there i got a executable file named test. Now i want to run it

```
sudo ./test

error: ./test: 1: ./test: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I install mono

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
sudo mono test.exe
```

error:

```
no such file on the directory
```

then i use

```
sudo mono test
```

error shows:

```
cannot open assembly'test':file does not contain a valid CIL image
```

How i could solve my problem. I want to convert my code(.py written in idle) into an executable file and run it on my raspberry pi.

Comment: Did you try `chmod` ?

Comment: Please, try with a simpler python script reproducing your problem, and add it to your question. Also: what is your pyinstaller and mono version ?

Comment: yes i use sudo chmod u+x test. but result is same

Comment: my test.py contains only print "hello". i am using python 2.7, pyinstaller 3.1 & mono 3.2.8

Comment: As i am using raspberry pi i changed pyinstaller bootloader name from linux-32bits to linux-32bits-arm

Comment: What does here involve mono?? Python is python, mono is mono, why did you tried to execute a python script under mono???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming linux-32bits to linux-32bits-arm still produces x86 files. You need compile own linux-32bits-arm bootloader.

In your PyInstaller distribution directory run:

```
cd bootloader
sudo python ./waf configure --no-lsb all
```

Then copy whole ../PyInstaller/bootloader/linux-32bits-arm to directory where did you renamed that bootloader

After that it should work ok.

Comment: i am not familiar with this process. kindly elaborate it. what does cd bootloader means is it cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader??? i issued the command from lx terminal here the compilers remains linux-64bit and linux -32bits know what i have to do???

Comment: from lx terminal i issued sudo python ./waf configure --no-lsb all error: cannot open ./waf: no such file

Comment: This is not right directory, you must download package with sources from https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases/download/v3.1/PyInstaller-3.1.zip, unpack it and there is folder bootloader with waf file inside it

Comment: thank you wallycz that was helpfull now I am able to run my test program. but my main program which contains RPI.GPIO, Tkinter,mysql,PIL is not running.at the 1st line my python command was import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  the error is : Import error : No module named RPi.GPIO

Comment: Have you installed RPI.GPIO library for Python3? `sudo pip install RPi.GPIO` and then again `sudo pyinstaller ./test.py`. It works for me...