# How do I build Python source as a Linux binary?

Tags: python

I'm a data engineer. Now I've developed a Python program and need to build it into a Linux binary. What do I do？

Comment: You can’t *really* do that, nor do you generally *need* to. At best you can use a wrapper binary that bundles your code, but (especially on Linux) this is very rarely necessary. Usually you’d distribute the scripts via an installer. — What’s your use-case?

Comment: As a data engineer using Linux and Python every day, I would need to know more about your use case to understand why it is necessary? You can execute python code from the linux terminal by using "python python_file_name.py" and execute linux code from Python e. g. by using "os.system(linux_command)".

Comment: 1 option is to freeze the code to an executable using [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/). second options is relevant in case your script serves as a module (or a package), than you can [package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) it

Comment: A couple of years ago I have created a .exe (on Windows) from a python program. I think that it also works on linux. I used the answer from Maria Irudaya Regilan J on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python) post.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to make a executable file
you can use

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

to install a installer
And
then uses this command for make a executable file :

```
pyinstaller yourprogram.py
```

and please read this post
[How to Run an executable file on Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430043/how-to-run-an-executable-file-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: You should mention that the binary in the case of pyinstaller still includes the source code — it doesn’t actually compile the Python code, it just bundles it with a minimal Python installation.